# Get rows inserted after the last fetch from a Mysql table without primary key

Tags: mysql, database

So, I have a table which has 3 columns.

`Customer_number`, `login_hash` and `some_hash`

The customer_number is not the auto increment id and the table is being indexed on login_hash. 
Now the table is updated every hour and new entries are being added. I have to get the new entries, use them for some calls and then store the resulting data.

My plan is to always store the last row number in some `last_row` environment variable and then retrieve values after that row number till the last record. Then update the `last_row` number.

How do I achieve this? And is there any better approach to this problem?

I know this is a bad table design but I have to deal with this and can't change it.